# How to write a function which accepts its own output as input and runs in a loop until a condition is met?

Tags: r, recursion, while-loop

I'm matching messy data across multiple fields. Here's a toy example.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(id = c("0049984000", "3502234000", "4029979100", 
                            "4331301000", "4690309000", "4690487000", "4690686000", "4702065000", 
                            "4980108200"), OWNER_NAME_1 = c("CLAUDEAN L RING REV TRUST", 
                                                            "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC", "SAM STAIR", "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP", 
                                                            "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC", "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC", "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC", 
                                                            "S2 REAL ESTATE", "S2 REAL EST GROUP"),
                     OWNER_MAIL_ADDR = c("2045 PARADISE DR", 
                                         "11512 W WOODSIDE DR", "2925 W LINCOLN AVE", "2925 W LINCOLN AVE", 
                                         "2925 W LINCOLN AV", "2925 W LINCOLN AVE", "2925 W LINCOLN AV", 
                                         "11512 W WOODSIDE DR", "2925 W LINCOLN AVE"), 
                     OWNER_CITY_STATE = c("WEST BEND, WI", 
                                          "HALES CORNERS, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI", 
                                          "MILWAUKEE, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI", "HALES CORNERS, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI"
                     )), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                     ))

df
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  id         OWNER_NAME_1               OWNER_MAIL_ADDR     OWNER_CITY_STATE 
  <chr>      <chr>                      <chr>               <chr>            
1 0049984000 CLAUDEAN L RING REV TRUST  2045 PARADISE DR    WEST BEND, WI    
2 3502234000 S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC 11512 W WOODSIDE DR HALES CORNERS, WI
3 4029979100 SAM STAIR                  2925 W LINCOLN AVE  MILWAUKEE, WI    
4 4331301000 S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP       2925 W LINCOLN AVE  MILWAUKEE, WI    
5 4690309000 S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC 2925 W LINCOLN AV   MILWAUKEE, WI    
6 4690487000 S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC 2925 W LINCOLN AVE  MILWAUKEE, WI    
7 4690686000 S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC 2925 W LINCOLN AV   MILWAUKEE, WI    
8 4702065000 S2 REAL ESTATE             11512 W WOODSIDE DR HALES CORNERS, WI
9 4980108200 S2 REAL EST GROUP          2925 W LINCOLN AVE  MILWAUKEE, WI
```

This function accepts a vector of `OWNER_NAME_1` values and returns **all** the values of `OWNER_NAME_1` which share an address.

```
# this function identifies all the OTHER names which share an address with the given name(s)
connect_owners_by_address <- function(landlord_names){
  # parcels owned by given landlord name(s)
  addresses1 <- df %>%
    filter(OWNER_NAME_1 %in% landlord_names) %>%
    group_by(OWNER_MAIL_ADDR, OWNER_CITY_STATE) %>%
    summarise() %>%
    ungroup()
  
  # all owner names at addresses associated with first name(s)
  names.at.addresses <- df %>%
    inner_join(addresses1, by = join_by(OWNER_MAIL_ADDR, OWNER_CITY_STATE)) %>%
    group_by(OWNER_NAME_1) %>%
    summarise()
  
  names.at.addresses$OWNER_NAME_1
}
```

The output of the function (a character vector of names) is the same format as the input. By running the function recursively on its own output, I can identify more matches.

For example:

```
# run once (4 matches)
connect_owners_by_address("SAM STAIR")
[1] "S2 REAL EST GROUP"          "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP"       "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC" "SAM STAIR"   

# run twice (5 matches)
connect_owners_by_address("SAM STAIR") |>
  connect_owners_by_address()
[1] "S2 REAL EST GROUP"          "S2 REAL ESTATE"             "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP"       "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC"
[5] "SAM STAIR" 

# run 3 times (still just 5 matches)
connect_owners_by_address("SAM STAIR") |>
  connect_owners_by_address() |>
  connect_owners_by_address()
[1] "S2 REAL EST GROUP"          "S2 REAL ESTATE"             "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP"       "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC"
[5] "SAM STAIR"
```

I would like to wrap my function `connect_owners_by_address` into another function which runs recursively on its own output and **stops** once the output length is equivalent to the input length--in this example, 5.

I think this will involve `while` loop, but I can't figure out how to supply the output of the function back to the input. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive wrapper:

```
connect_owners_by_address_recursive <- function(landlord_names, length.out){
  names.at.addresses <- connect_owners_by_address(landlord_names)
    
  if(length(names.at.addresses) < length.out){
    names.at.addresses <- connect_owners_by_address_recursive(names.at.addresses, length.out)
  }
  
  names.at.addresses
}
```

While loop wrapper:

```
connect_owners_by_address_while <- function(landlord_names, length.out){
  names.at.addresses <- connect_owners_by_address(landlord_names)
  
  while(length(names.at.addresses) < length.out){
    names.at.addresses <- connect_owners_by_address(names.at.addresses)
  }
  
  names.at.addresses
}
```

Turning original function into a recursive one:

```
connect_owners_by_address <- function(landlord_names, length.out = NULL){
  # parcels owned by given landlord name(s)
  addresses1 <- df %>%
    filter(OWNER_NAME_1 %in% landlord_names) %>%
    group_by(OWNER_MAIL_ADDR, OWNER_CITY_STATE) %>%
    summarise() %>%
    ungroup()
  
  # all owner names at addresses associated with first name(s)
  names.at.addresses <- df %>%
    inner_join(addresses1, by = join_by(OWNER_CITY_STATE, OWNER_MAIL_ADDR)) %>%
    group_by(OWNER_NAME_1) %>%
    summarise() %>%
    pull(OWNER_NAME_1)
  
  if(!is.null(length.out) && length(names.at.addresses) < length.out){
    connect_owners_by_address(names.at.addresses)
  } else{
    names.at.addresses
  }
}
```

Obs: the use of `pull()` makes the function cleaner in my opinion. Also, if you don't want to use it recursively, just don't pass `length.out`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a recursive function. You can try this.

```
f <- function(x, d=df) {
  m <- unique(merge(d, d[d$OWNER_NAME_1 %in% x, c("OWNER_MAIL_ADDR", "OWNER_CITY_STATE")])[, 'OWNER_NAME_1'])
  if (identical(length(m), length(x))) {
    return(x)
  } else {
    f(m, d)
  }
}

f("SAM STAIR")
# [1] "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC" "S2 REAL ESTATE"             "SAM STAIR"                  "S2 REAL EST GROUP"         
# [5] "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP"
```

No extra packages involved.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("0049984000", "3502234000", "4029979100", 
"4331301000", "4690309000", "4690487000", "4690686000", "4702065000", 
"4980108200"), OWNER_NAME_1 = c("CLAUDEAN L RING REV TRUST", 
"S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC", "SAM STAIR", "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP", 
"S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC", "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC", "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC", 
"S2 REAL ESTATE", "S2 REAL EST GROUP"), OWNER_MAIL_ADDR = c("2045 PARADISE DR", 
"11512 W WOODSIDE DR", "2925 W LINCOLN AVE", "2925 W LINCOLN AVE", 
"2925 W LINCOLN AV", "2925 W LINCOLN AVE", "2925 W LINCOLN AV", 
"11512 W WOODSIDE DR", "2925 W LINCOLN AVE"), OWNER_CITY_STATE = c("WEST BEND, WI", 
"HALES CORNERS, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI", 
"MILWAUKEE, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI", "HALES CORNERS, WI", "MILWAUKEE, WI"
)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to run the function iteratively and explicitly set maximum number of iteration, which avoids infinite loop.

```
run_myfunction_iteratively <- function(df,input,niter=1000){
  for(i in seq(niter)){
    message(paste0("iteration: ",i))
    if(i==1){
      old_out <- new_out <- connect_owners_by_address(input)
    }else{
      new_out <- connect_owners_by_address(new_out)
      if(length(old_out)==length(new_out)){
        return(new_out)
      }else{
        old_out <- new_out
      }
    }
  }
  warning(paste0("The function does not converge in ",niter," iterations."))
}

run_myfunction_iteratively(df,"SAM STAIR",niter=10)
iteration: 1
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'OWNER_MAIL_ADDR'. You can override using the `.groups`
argument.
iteration: 2
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'OWNER_MAIL_ADDR'. You can override using the `.groups`
argument.
iteration: 3
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'OWNER_MAIL_ADDR'. You can override using the `.groups`
argument.
[1] "S2 REAL EST GROUP"          "S2 REAL ESTATE"             "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP"      
[4] "S2 REAL ESTATE GROUP 5 LLC" "SAM STAIR"
```